# Calculate new value in MariaDB based on values in the previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

In MariaDB 10.3, I have a table like this:

| id | date | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 120 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 130 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 140 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 150 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 160 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 170 |

I need to calculate the remaining sum after every date. Something like this.
I need the calculation to happen as a query in the MariaDB.

| id | date | sum | remaining total sum before pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 120 | 870 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 130 | 750 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 140 | 620 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 150 | 480 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 160 | 330 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 170 | 170 |

I found a few close solutions but can't alter them in a proper way to suit my need. Any ideas would be appreciated.

The logic for the last column is:

1. The first value is the whole sum owed (120+130+140...)
2. Every next value is calculated from that number decreased by the value in the sum column on the same  row
   i.e.

- 870-120=750;
- 750-130=620;
- 620-140=480;  etc.

My attempt was:

1. First queries which were close, but didn't work:

```
    SELECT 
    id,s.sum,s.date,
    @b := @b + s.sum   AS balance
    FROM
    (SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
      CROSS JOIN
        tpp AS s
        where id=1
    ORDER BY
        s.date ;
```

The result was:

| id | date | sum | remaining total sum before pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 120 | 120 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 130 | 250 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 140 | 380 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 150 | 520 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 160 | 670 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 170 | 840 |

I.e. it kind of reversed the result. And increased the value with the value on the next row.

2. The other query was with the LAG function but the subtracting part was disappointing

```
    SELECT 
    id,date,
    sum(sum)-LAG(sum) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS l
    FROM tpp
    where id=1
    group by date,id
    ORDER BY date
```

And the result:

| id | date | remaining total sum before pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | null |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 10 |

It subtracted:

- 130-120=10;
- 140-130=10;
- 150-140=10;  etc.

Comment: Why is 870 the first number in the sum column? You haven't explained the logic. Why is that the "remaining" total. Remaining from what? There's nothing in the table to relate it to, and thus no means of calculating it.

Comment: Also, if the subsequent rows are supposed to be the result of subtracting the current "sum" from the previous remaining total, then several of them are incorrect. e.g. 870-130 does not equal 750. You need to clarify your whole question. It would also help if you showed some previous effort to write a query to solve it, based on information you found - what query / queries did you try? Please show the one which got you closest to the solution, and explain where it went wrong.

Comment: Oh, and please tell us what version of mysql you use. And also you could read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: someone closed that really quickly, a? kind of ok now?

Comment: You need to show your current query and what goes wrong. To be honest, if you need this data for your frontend you could calculate them there way easier.

Comment: I will need a few minutes to show the queries in a proper format...

Comment: Questions do get closed quickly here yes, especially on the busy tags. You really need to ensure you provide all necessary information up-front. Remember we know _nothing_ about your scenario except what you tell us. So if it's unclear, you'll find out about it pretty fast usually. Luckily, you now only need one more vote for it to be re-opened. I expect if you add your current code attempt you'll get that vote fairly soon.

Comment: Also just a tip, there are reasons why people separate stock and transaction data.

Comment: queries,results and explanations added.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only SUM() window function:

```
SELECT id, date,
       SUM(sum) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS l
FROM tpp
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a0f8c8a9b24fe1c0f37eb22380ce3b3c).
Results:

```
> id | date       |   l
> -: | :--------- | --:
>  1 | 2020-01-01 | 870
>  1 | 2020-02-01 | 750
>  1 | 2020-03-01 | 620
>  1 | 2020-04-01 | 480
>  1 | 2020-05-01 | 330
>  1 | 2020-06-01 | 170
```